# stuck with convert json to csv: finding the right attributes and converting

Tags: python, json, csv, attributes

Im completely new to python and I'm trying to receive all tweets from a list of user names.

My code works so far as it is retreiving the right tweets, but I need to use the data afterwards as a table such as csv or excel. There are about 8.000 usernames and I have various difficulties with online and software converters (such as https://konklone.io/json/ or Alteryx).

Thus I need to save the received data directly in a csv or excel table. How do I adapt the code to convert the json string into a list of columns and save it in an table file?

This is my code:

```
from twitterscraper import query_tweets
from twitterscraper.main import JSONEncoder
import json
import csv
import datetime as dt


with open('account_list.txt', 'r') as f:
    handles = f.readlines()

handles = [h.rstrip('\n') for h in handles]

all_tweets = {}
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for handle in handles:
        all_tweets[handle] = query_tweets(f"from:{handle}", limit=10000, begindate=dt.date(2010,1,1), enddate=dt.date.today(), poolsize=10, lang='')
        print ({handle})

    outtweets = [[tweet.fullname_str, tweet.id, tweet.likes, tweet.replies, tweet.retweets, tweet.text.encode('utf-8'),tweet.timestamp,tweet.url,tweet.user] for tweet in all_tweets]

    with open('all_tweets.csv', 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(["fullname","id","likes","replies","retweets","text","timestamp","url","user"])
        writer.writerows(outtweets)
```

As you can see, I tried to adapt solutions that were already posted but I get the error in creating the outtweets because "fullname" is not a valid attribute. How do I adapt the code or find out the right attribute names? I tried to exchange e.g. tweet.fullname_str into query_tweets.fullname_string (and so on) but I get the same mistake.

This is the JSON Structure right now (just an example extract of course):

```
{
"ladygaga": [
{
"fullname": "Lady Gaga",
"id": "28430069310",
"likes": "2604",
"replies": "68",
"retweets": "5038",
"text": "We are not just Art for Michelangelo to carve, he can't rewrite the agro of my furied heart",
"timestamp": "2010-10-22T18:41:50",
"url": "/ladygaga/status/28430069310",
"user": "ladygaga"
},
{....
}, 
],
"tomhanks": [
{
"fullname": "Tom Hanks"
"id": .....
}
]
}
```

Help is highly appreciated!!

EDIT: This is the code before I tried to change it to csv Output and that was working fine:

```
from twitterscraper import query_tweets
from twitterscraper.main import JSONEncoder
import json
import datetime as dt


with open('account_list.txt', 'r') as f:
    handles = f.readlines()

handles = [h.rstrip('\n') for h in handles]

all_tweets = {}
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for handle in handles:
         all_tweets[handle] = query_tweets(f"from:{handle}", limit=10000, begindate=dt.date(2010,1,1), enddate=dt.date.today(), poolsize=10, lang='')
         print ({handle})

    with open('all_tweets.json', 'a') as f:
        json.dump(all_tweets, f, cls=JSONEncoder)
```

Comment: Can you show the print statement of all_tweets?

Comment: Hi @rakesh sure! I updated the question with the code that was working before I tried to save the data in the csv. The output of print(all_tweets) befor the outtweets looks incredibly wrong, it's sth like this: {'ladygaga': [<twitterscraper.tweet.Tweet object at 0x00000198808F6BE0>, <twitterscraper.tweet.Tweet object at 0x00000198808F6E10>, <twitterscraper.tweet.Tweet object at 0x00000198808F6EF0>, <twitterscraper.tweet.Tweet object at 0x00000198808F6F98>, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Replace

```
outtweets = [[tweet.fullname_str, tweet.id, tweet.likes, tweet.replies, tweet.retweets, tweet.text.encode('utf-8'),tweet.timestamp,tweet.url,tweet.user] for tweet in all_tweets]
```

with

```
outtweets = [[tweet.fullname, tweet.id, tweet.likes, tweet.replies, tweet.retweets, tweet.text.encode('utf-8'),tweet.timestamp,tweet.url,tweet.user] for tweet in all_tweets['ladygaga']]
```

Comment: Hi @rakesh thanks for your support! I tried that but I still get the AttributeError: 'Tweet' object has no attribute 'fullname_str' Also there is more than one username so shouldn't this be {handle} instead of ladygaga then? Thanks!!

Comment: Can you try the above snippet?

Comment: So many thanks for your effort! This yields in following error: "TypeError: 'Tweet' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: outtweets = [[tweet.fullname, tweet.id, tweet.likes, tweet.replies, tweet.retweets, tweet.text.encode('utf-8'),tweet.timestamp,tweet.url,tweet.user] for tweet in all_tweets['ladygaga']]

Comment: It works, it works - almost! :) Right now it only shows me Lady Gaga Tweets because of this expression: "for tweet in all_tweets['ladygaga']" but I'm going through a list of usernames (e.g. second name in the list would be Tom Hanks). How do I get his tweets into the csv, too?

Comment: You can add an additional loop to access them

Comment: EX: outtweets = [[tweet.fullname, tweet.id, tweet.likes, tweet.replies, tweet.retweets, tweet.text.encode('utf-8'),tweet.timestamp,tweet.url,tweet.user] for account in all_tweets for tweet in all_tweets[account]]

Comment: Hi @Rakesh, sorry for the late reply, I did some extensive testing :) It works, thank you so much! May I ask you: since it's a lot of usernames I have a memory error when writing all the data into the file at the end. If, however, I write the data into the file each time in the loop, I get a lot (!) of multiples. Can you guess why? I added the f.close() at the end but the error remains even without that expression.